# Magento 2 catalog price rules based on session variable

Tags: magento2, affiliate, promotions

I would like to apply catalog price rules based on a session variable that I will store for some customer segments.
For example, if a customer visits the site with a specific URL parameter, I would apply some catalog price rules, that will accompany the customer throughout his visit in the site.

-- EDIT --
Another option, could be, to assign a guest customer to a customer group somehow, and the group can be associated with catalog price rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable request however customers are familiar with websites that use coupons.

You can add a coupon by observing a landing page and applying a coupon to a basket, then showing a customer message that tells them coupon NNN has been applied and that they will get their discount at the checkout automatically.

```
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()->save();
```

Works great, with Magento1 you needed to store a coupon in a cookie and apply it when something was added to the cart. With M2 there is no need for this, you can add an observer that just does the above.

Comment: Hi Mavis, 
my idea is to apply the discount prices to the catalog, before it is in the cart

Comment: I would say that it cannot be done and that you would be better to advise your client that the customer is used to the automatic coupon approach. I wish you luck!